# Search categorie count to an id

Tags: mysql

My table looks like this:

```
+----------+-------------+------------+
| Username | AccountName |  Created   |
+----------+-------------+------------+
| User1    | Account1    | 10.09.2020 |
| User2    | Account2    | 09.10.2020 |
| User1    | Account1    | 11.10.2020 |
| User1    | Account3    | 15.10.2020 |
+----------+-------------+------------+
```

I want to query this table to show me only usernames and accountname where accountname >1 in cndition with a date.

My current try is this:

```
SELECT username, accountname FROM `profit_log` WHERE 
created > '2020-09-31 00:00:00' and accountname >'' 
group by username, accountname 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT AccountName, username > 1)
```

Datenbank-Client Version: libmysql - 5.6.43

Comment: *where accountname >1* o_O `accountname` column is string it's strange to compare it with the number...

Comment: Specify precise MySQL version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need

```sql
SELECT profit_log.*
FROM profit_log 
JOIN ( -- select account names which have duplicates within specified date range
       SELECT accountname
       FROM profit_log 
       WHERE created >= '2020-09-30 00:00:00'
       GROUP BY accountname
       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
       -- if accounts with the same username are not duplicates the use
       -- HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT username) > 1 
     ) subquery ON profit_log.accountname = subquery.accountname
WHERE profit_log.created >= '2020-09-30 00:00:00'
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9f91190522f46ab0b02cf869ee1d8a56) (source data changed slightly).

Comment: Thanks for you help so far !
I added the mysql version.
Moreover I ahd a little typo! I am very sorry for this! I you can, please take a look at last table entry. "User 1 Account3 15.10.2020"
The query result should be:
[User1 Account1,
User1 Account3] or [User1 (AccountCount)2]

Comment: @Felix ?? You need to find does the same user has created a lot of accounts? Simply swap `accountname` and `username` in my query...